# Application using TLSv1 even protocol configure to SSL_TLSv2

Tags: java, ssl, websphere, protocols, tls1.2

Good day,

In my UAT environment, in my WAS Console setting, I configure the protocol to `SSL_TLSv2`.

From https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_8.0.0/com.ibm.java.security.component.80.doc/security-component/jsse2Docs/protocols.html

`SSL_TLSv2` is enables all SSL v3.0 and TLS v1.0, v1.1 and v1.2 protocols. Accepts SSLv3 or TLSv1 hello encapsulated in an SSLv2 format hello. As the third party I am calling is using TLSv1.1 and above.

However, I am not sure why my application keep using `TLSv1` to call to this third party. But, in my local, my application will use `TLS1.2`.

The log is very long, I just copy part of it here:

```
[5/31/17 11:01:30:295 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O Using SSLEngineImpl.
[5/31/17 11:01:30:295 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O 
Is initial handshake: true
[5/31/17 11:01:30:296 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O WebContainer : 8, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 206
[5/31/17 11:01:30:296 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
[5/31/17 11:01:30:296 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O RandomCookie:  GMT: 831831437 bytes = { 93, 8, 167, 93, 70, 165, 107, 130, 22, 192, 168, 237, 31, 40, 47, 53, 32, 239, 89, 60, 125, 9, 14, 94, 61, 235, 71, 41 }
[5/31/17 11:01:30:296 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O Session ID:  {89, 46, 54, 117, 144, 143, 67, 159, 175, 15, 159, 221, 239, 101, 197, 29, 5, 194, 1, 42, 237, 228, 5, 25, 227, 117, 0, 64, 30, 148, 37, 23}
[5/31/17 11:01:30:296 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O Cipher Suites: [Unknown 0x3a:0x3a, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, Unknown 0xcc:0xa9, Unknown 0xcc:0xa8, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
[5/31/17 11:01:30:296 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O Compression Methods:  { 0 }
[5/31/17 11:01:30:296 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O Unsupported extension type_47802, data: 
[5/31/17 11:01:30:296 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O Extension renegotiation_info, ri_length: 0, ri_connection_data: { null }
[5/31/17 11:01:30:296 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O Unsupported extension type_23, data: 
[5/31/17 11:01:30:296 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O Unsupported extension type_35, data: 
[5/31/17 11:01:30:296 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA256withECDSA, Unknown (hash:0x8, signature:0x4), SHA256withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, Unknown (hash:0x8, signature:0x5), SHA384withRSA, Unknown (hash:0x8, signature:0x6), SHA512withRSA, SHA1withRSA
[5/31/17 11:01:30:296 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O Unsupported extension status_request, data: 01:00:00:00:00
[5/31/17 11:01:30:296 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O Unsupported extension type_18, data: 
[5/31/17 11:01:30:296 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O Unsupported extension type_16, data: 00:0c:02:68:32:08:68:74:74:70:2f:31:2e:31
[5/31/17 11:01:30:296 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O Unsupported extension type_30032, data: 
[5/31/17 11:01:30:296 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
[5/31/17 11:01:30:296 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {unknown curve 39578, unknown curve 29, secp256r1, secp384r1}
[5/31/17 11:01:30:296 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O Unsupported extension type_35466, data: 00
[5/31/17 11:01:30:296 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O ***
[5/31/17 11:01:30:297 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O [read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 206
```

...

```
[5/31/17 11:01:30:297 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O %% Resuming [Session-31, SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
[5/31/17 11:01:30:297 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O JsseJCE:  Using MessageDigest SHA-256 from provider IBMJCE version 1.2
[5/31/17 11:01:30:297 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O *** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
[5/31/17 11:01:30:297 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O RandomCookie:  GMT: 1496203290 bytes = { 165, 172, 157, 204, 255, 125, 192, 235, 102, 241, 157, 82, 77, 251, 31, 138, 77, 225, 201, 196, 50, 133, 137, 206, 255, 217, 204, 160 }
[5/31/17 11:01:30:297 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O Session ID:  {89, 46, 54, 117, 144, 143, 67, 159, 175, 15, 159, 221, 239, 101, 197, 29, 5, 194, 1, 42, 237, 228, 5, 25, 227, 117, 0, 64, 30, 148, 37, 23}
[5/31/17 11:01:30:297 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
[5/31/17 11:01:30:297 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O Compression Method: 0
[5/31/17 11:01:30:297 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O Extension renegotiation_info, ri_length: 0, ri_connection_data: { null }
[5/31/17 11:01:30:297 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O ***
[5/31/17 11:01:30:297 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O Cipher suite:  SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
[5/31/17 11:01:30:297 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O JsseJCE:  Using KeyGenerator IbmTls12KeyMaterial from provider TBD via init 
[5/31/17 11:01:30:297 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O CONNECTION KEYGEN:
[5/31/17 11:01:30:298 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O Client Nonce:
```

...

But in my local, it will very smart to know to use `TLSv1.2`.

Kindly advise how to make the application using `TLSv1.2`.

The error log as follow:

```
2017-05-31 11:01:30.421 [WebContainer : 8] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - [5001032maker] - Sending request: CONNECT api3.infobip.com:443 HTTP/1.1
2017-05-31 11:01:30.421 [WebContainer : 8] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - [5001032maker] - >> "CONNECT api3.infobip.com:443 HTTP/1.1[EOL]"
2017-05-31 11:01:30.421 [WebContainer : 8] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - [5001032maker] - >> "Host: api3.infobip.com[EOL]"
2017-05-31 11:01:30.421 [WebContainer : 8] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - [5001032maker] - >> "Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive[EOL]"
2017-05-31 11:01:30.421 [WebContainer : 8] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - [5001032maker] - >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.0.1 (java 1.5)[EOL]"
2017-05-31 11:01:30.421 [WebContainer : 8] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - [5001032maker] - >> "[EOL]"
2017-05-31 11:01:30.421 [WebContainer : 8] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - [5001032maker] - >> CONNECT api3.infobip.com:443 HTTP/1.1
2017-05-31 11:01:30.421 [WebContainer : 8] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - [5001032maker] - >> Host: api3.infobip.com
2017-05-31 11:01:30.421 [WebContainer : 8] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - [5001032maker] - >> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
2017-05-31 11:01:30.421 [WebContainer : 8] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - [5001032maker] - >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.0.1 (java 1.5)
2017-05-31 11:01:30.778 [WebContainer : 8] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - [5001032maker] - << "HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established[EOL]"
2017-05-31 11:01:30.778 [WebContainer : 8] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - [5001032maker] - << "Proxy-agent: IBM_HTTP_Server[EOL]"
2017-05-31 11:01:30.778 [WebContainer : 8] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - [5001032maker] - << "[EOL]"
2017-05-31 11:01:30.778 [WebContainer : 8] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - [5001032maker] - Receiving response: HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
2017-05-31 11:01:30.778 [WebContainer : 8] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - [5001032maker] - << HTTP/1.0 200 Connection Established
2017-05-31 11:01:30.778 [WebContainer : 8] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - [5001032maker] - << Proxy-agent: IBM_HTTP_Server
2017-05-31 11:01:30.779 [WebContainer : 8] DEBUG o.a.h.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient - [5001032maker] - Tunnel to target created.
2017-05-31 11:01:31.134 [WebContainer : 8] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.DefaultClientConnection - [5001032maker] - Connection shut down
2017-05-31 11:01:31.134 [WebContainer : 8] DEBUG o.a.h.i.conn.SingleClientConnManager - [5001032maker] - Releasing connection org.apache.http.impl.conn.SingleClientConnManager$ConnAdapter@33b3d257
2017-05-31 11:01:31.144 [WebContainer : 8] ERROR o.a.c.processor.DeadLetterChannel - [5001032maker] - Failed delivery for exchangeId: ID-uatgibapp01.hlbho.hlbank.my/56300-1496200314511/0-9. On delivery attempt: 0 caught: retrofit.RetrofitError: peer not authenticated
retrofit.RetrofitError: peer not authenticated
    at retrofit.RetrofitError.networkError(RetrofitError.java:27) ~[retrofit-1.9.0.jar:na]
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:395) ~[retrofit-1.9.0.jar:na]
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240) ~[retrofit-1.9.0.jar:na]
    at infobip.api.client.$Proxy328.execute(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at infobip.api.client.SendSingleTextualSms.execute(SendSingleTextualSms.java:49) ~[infobip-api-java-client-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.cv.ibs.infobip.notification.camel.InfoBipWebServiceProcessor.process(InfoBipWebServiceProcessor.java:43) ~[com.cv.ibs.cib.ws.jar:na]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AsyncProcessorTypeConverter$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorTypeConverter.java:43) ~[camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DeadLetterChannel.process(DeadLetterChannel.java:172) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DeadLetterChannel.process(DeadLetterChannel.java:93) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:115) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:89) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:47) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:41) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:66) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:47) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:151) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:136) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:93) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:75) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.request(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:172) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
```

...

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:17) ~[na:6.0 build_20140221]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128) ~[com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:399) ~[com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.updateSecureConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:167) ~[com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.layerProtocol(AbstractPoolEntry.java:275) ~[com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.layerProtocol(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:138) ~[com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.establishRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:704) ~[com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:421) ~[com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:641) ~[com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:576) ~[com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:554) ~[com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar:na]
    at retrofit.client.ApacheClient.execute(ApacheClient.java:71) ~[retrofit-1.9.0.jar:na]
    at retrofit.client.ApacheClient.execute(ApacheClient.java:65) ~[retrofit-1.9.0.jar:na]
    at com.cv.ibs.infobip.notification.camel.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:45) ~[com.cv.ibs.cib.ws.jar:na]
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:326) ~[retrofit-1.9.0.jar:na]
    ... 173 common frames omitted
```

Comment: The error here is 'peer not authenticated'. It has nothing to do with the TLS version whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> [5/31/17 11:01:30:296 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O WebContainer : 8, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 206
> [5/31/17 11:01:30:296 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O *** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
> ...
> [5/31/17 11:01:30:297 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O *** ServerHello, TLSv1.2
> [5/31/17 11:01:30:297 ICT] 000000ca SystemOut     O Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
> ```

The debug output you show clearly indicates that both client and server are using TLS 1.2, i.e. the version of the ClientHello is TLS 1.2, the version of the ServerHello too and the shared cipher is also a cipher available only since TLS 1.2. You might wonder that the TLS 1.2 ClientHello is wrapped into a TLS 1.0 record but this is pretty normal.

Comment: Means my application are using TLSv1.2 to do the connection? But I am still hitting the `peer not authenticated` error. I already put in the error log, can you help me have a look?

Comment: @PanadolChong: peer not authenticated is a different issue and has nothing to do with the TLS protocol version. Please don't change the focus of the question but instead ask a new question with enough details. My guess is that the certificate of the server can not be validated by the client either because the trust chain is incomplete or the root CA is not trusted - but there are not enough information to be sure. Thus please ask a new question with enough details.

Comment: Hi @Steffen , may I know the error message if TLS protocol is wrong? Because I thought it was cause by wrong TLS version from the log.

Comment: @PanadolChong: in this case you get usually something like "handshake error" or "alert bad protocol".

Comment: I will post a new question on it. What information I should provide so that people can know the details?

Comment: @PanadolChong: The SSL debug output might be a useful start, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html

Comment: I just create a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44280943/caused-by-java-lang-exception-truststore-file-does-not-exist-truststore(After I add in -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=trustStore), could you help to have a look on it?